# On Modes of Convergence

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

I was searching for a counter example of the fact that convergence in moments ($\mathbb{E}|X_n|^p \to \mathbb{E}|X|^p$) does not necessarily imply $\mathcal{L}^p$ convergence ($\mathbb{E}|X_n - X|^p \to 0$). (Here $p$ could be < 1).

Answer (score 3):

Try $X_n=-X$ for every $n$, for some symmetric random variable $X$.

Comment: I feel like an idiot.

Comment: Bad idea in maths :-) (to feel like an idiot, I mean).